# Given a triangle in 3D space whose vertices are known, what is the easiest way to compute the point of intersection between the altitude and the base?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are the vertices of the triangle, and suppose we choose an arbitrary base, let's say $AC$. What would be the easiest way to find the coordinates of the other point that defines the altitude, let's call it $B^{\prime}$?

Comment: Check https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72528/how-can-i-project-a-3d-point-onto-a-3d-line

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Vasya!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine the unit vector $$\bf n = \frac{\vec{AC}}{|AC|}$$ along the base.

Then $$\vec{AB'}= \vec{AB} \cdot \bf n$$